# LDC Theorem and Hardy-Littlewood Function question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to show that for any $r >0$ and $f \in L^1$ then $A_{f,r} := \frac{1}{m(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y)dm(y)$ is also $L^1$. In fact we can show that $\|A_{f,r}\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1$ where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $L^1$ norm.

I'm not really sure how to approach this, but I feel like Tonelli's theorem could be helpful.

Any suggestions for a starting point would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\chi_r(x)$ be the characteristic function of $B(0,r)$ divided by its measure. Then $\chi_r\in L^1$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_r(x)\,dx=1$ and
$$
A_{f,r}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_r(x-y)\,f(y)\,dy=(\chi_r\ast f)(x).
$$
I hope you can continue from here (using Fubini's theorem.)

Comment: don't you forgot about coefficient $\frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot. Thank's for pointing it out. I will edit muy answer.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it, clever move with characteristic function. It seems that many of the problems I've been working on can be simplified by employing that trick.